# Can the External Accessory Framework connect to Bluetooth v4.0 classic?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, accessory

I am working on fixing an application for a client. Using the BT43 module, whose datasheet supports bluetooth v4.0 classic AND low energy. Mind you, this device also has the MFi Authentication chip! However, my problem is as such:

I can connect to the device on a system level, however in my test application...

`[[EAManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]`

returns an empty array.
If I show the built in bluetooth picker, the device also shows up, however fails to connect.
Core Bluetooth can see and connect to it via LightBlue though.

My question is, could this be a hardware issue, or an iOS 8.1.2 bug with Bluetooth Core Specification v4.0?

Comment: Sounds like maybe it has to be configured to *either* classic or LE, and that it's currently in LE. Anything in the data sheet about changing the mode on chip boot?

Comment: good suggestion, currently looking that up now

Comment: @mbm29414 nothing in the datasheet says anything about switching operation modes

Comment: it sounds like you need to connect through Core Bluetooth/BLE. This is much simpler than using External Accoessory framework in terms of app approval

Comment: @Paulw11 But that's not his question, and if he has high-data-throughput needs, BLE is likely insufficient.

Comment: @JoeyLaBarck Can you confirm that you have an MFi-compatible chip? I saw that both the BT43S and BT43H are iOS-compatible, but are you **absolutely** certain the co-processor is on your board?

Comment: Then he will need to ensure that he has installed the AmpedUp software on the device, that it actually has an MFi chip and eventually join the MFi program to get his own MFi licensed chips

Comment: @mbm29414 positive its on there. I just tried scanning with the corebluetooth framework as well, still can't connect to it through either framework... weird

Comment: Have you put the accessory Id into your info.plist?

Comment: The corebluetooth can connect to the device, yet is visible to the external accessory framework, which makes sense, the BT module is a dual mode device. The company which makes the device I am interfacing has pointed the MFi chip out to me.The company is registered, and licensed with MFi Program too. I can only assume this device in particular is faulty or needs to be re-flashed, however... corebluetooth is able to communicate.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have not read anything about putting the accessory id in the info.plist, only the supported protocols...

Comment: Sorry, That is what I meant

Comment: @JoeyLaBarck I'm confused. Is it working with CoreBluetooth or not? You've said both "yes" and "no" in previous comments.

Comment: Yes it works with corebluetooth, I made a minor mistake connecting to the peripheral. However, it should support EA framework, if visible through the framework... Im going to try and pull some error codes if I can.

Comment: Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain error 1.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the wiring on the authentication coprocessor being wrong, as well as the firmware out of date.